# Coefficient of $x^{n-3}$ in $\prod^{n}_{k=1}(x-k)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Finding Coefficient of $x^{n-3}$ in $\displaystyle \prod^{n}_{k=1}(x-k)$

what i try

$\displaystyle \prod^{n}_{k=1}(x-k)=x^n-\bigg(\sum^{n}_{i=1}i\bigg)+\bigg(\mathop{\sum\sum}_{1\leq i <j \leq n}ij\bigg)x^{n-2}-\bigg(\mathop{\sum\sum\sum}_{1\leq i <j<k\leq n}ijk\bigg)x^{n-3}+\cdots $

How do i find $\displaystyle \bigg(\mathop{\sum\sum\sum}_{1\leq i <j<k\leq n}ijk\bigg)$ help me please

Comment: Using [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities), you can express the sum at hand in terms of $\sum_{k=1}^n k^\ell$ for $\ell = 1, 2, 3$...

Comment: @achille hui did not understand last line.please explain me thanks

Answer (score 2):

For every positive integer $n$, let $c_{n,j}=0$ if $j<0$ or $j>n$ and
$$\prod_{k=1}^n(x+k)=\sum_{j=0}^nc_{n,j}x^{n-j}$$
Then
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}c_{n+1,j}x^{n+1-j}
&=\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}(x+k)\\
&=(x+n+1)\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x+k)\\
&=(x+n+1)\sum_{j=0}^nc_{n,j}x^{n-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^nc_{n,j}x^{n+1-j}+\sum_{j=0}^n(n+1)c_{n,j}x^{n-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^nc_{n,j}x^{n+1-j}+\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}(n+1)c_{n,j-1}x^{n+1-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n(c_{n,j}+(n+1)c_{n,j-1})x^{n+1-j}
\end{align}
from which
$$c_{n+1,j}=c_{n,j}+(n+1)c_{n,j-1}$$
hence
\begin{align}
c_{N,j}-c_{1,j}
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(c_{n+1,j}-c_{n,j})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(n+1)c_{n,j-1}
\end{align}
that's
$$c_{N,j}=c_{1,j}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(n+1)c_{n,j-1}$$
Since $c_{n,0}=1$, we get
\begin{align}
c_{N,1}
&=c_{1,1}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(n+1)c_{n,0}\\
&=1+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(n+1)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N n\\
&=\frac 12 N(N+1)\\
c_{N,2}
&=c_{1,2}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(n+1)c_{n,1}\\
&=\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}n(n+1)^2\\
&=\frac 1{24}(N - 1) N (N + 1) (3 N + 2)\\
c_{N,3}
&=c_{1,3}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(n+1)c_{n,2}\\
&=\frac 1{24}\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(n - 1) n (n + 1)^2 (3 n + 2)\\
&=\frac 1{48}(N - 2) (N - 1) N^2 (N + 1)^2
\end{align}